# comprehension - make a list out of a dictionary fields

Tags: python, python-2.7, set

Currently, I am doing this:

```
nodes = set([relation.source for relation in relations] +
            [relation.target for relation in relations])
```

For sure there must be an easier way, but I can't find it.

Something like

```
nodes = set([(relation.source, relation.target) for relation in relations])
```

but of course this doesn't work.
Thanks

**[EDIT]**
Forgot to mention:
relations is a dictionary, or in my case, a collection of objects.

Answer (score 3):

You can use multiple `for` clauses in *-comprehension (list, set, dict, generator expression):

```
nodes = {
    x
    for relation in relations
    for x in [relation.source, relation.target]
}
```

Above expression is similar to:

```
nodes = set()
for relation in relations:
    for x in [relation.source, relation.target]:
        nodes.add(x)
nodes
```

---

Alternative using a generation function:

```
def source_targets(relations):
    for relation in relations:
        yield relation.source
        yield relation.target

nodes = set(source_targets(relations))
```

Comment: yes, I think this was. I believe a better logic though would be to switch the ``for`` ordering

Comment: @MihaiZamfir, No, you can't switch. If you switch the order, it become different expression; for this specific code, it will raise error.  I updated the answer. Checking will help you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable), this may perform a little better than a set comprehension:

```
from itertools import chain

nodes = set(chain.from_iterable((r.source, r.target) for r in relations))
```